# Apache Artemis: How can i create Durable Subscription for Static Clustered

Tags: activemq-artemis

here is example of [clustered-durable-subscription](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/master/examples/features/clustered/clustered-durable-subscription) and here is [clustered-static-discovery](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/master/examples/features/clustered/clustered-static-discovery), In clustered-static-discovery connecting with only one server (cluster auto connected with another server using cluster configuration).
As per doc

> Normally durable subscriptions exist on a single node and can only
>   have one subscriber at any one time, however, with ActiveMQ Artemis
>   it's possible to create durable subscription instances with the same
>   name and client-id on different nodes of the cluster, and consume from
>   them simultaneously. This allows the work of processing messages from
>   a durable subscription to be spread across the cluster in a similar
>   way to how JMS Queues can be load balanced across the cluster

Should i need to add additional config for static cluster, or durable-subscription will work fine with static cluster without set the client id and subscription for all node of(As i have mentioned in static cluster we only make connection with one node)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "static" part of the "clustered-static-discovery" really only refers to cluster node *discovery* (as the name suggests).  Once the cluster nodes are discovered and the cluster is formed then the cluster will behave the same as if the discovery were dynamic (e.g. using UDP multicast).  In other words, a clustered durable subscription should work the same no matter what mechanism was used on the server-side for cluster node discovery.

Comment: Justin 
In static clustered-static-discovery if i have set same client id for all 4 connection then i am getting exception: ```javax.jms.InvalidClientIDException: clientID=my-client-id was already set into another connection```
So how we can share a commanon id for all connection.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/jbertram/activemq-artemis/tree/clustered-durable-subscription-static-discovery/examples/features/clustered/clustered-static-discovery.  I modified the clustered-static-discovery example to use durable subscriptions.  If you run it you'll see that it works.  If you're setting the same client ID and subscription name when you connect you need to ensure you're connecting to a node that doesn't already have a subscriber connected.